# How should method names be named in a send/receive environment?

Tags: python, oop

This question is posed in a python context but extends to other languages. What I am doing is creating a simulation for distributes systems in a network and I want to have the ability of sending messages from nodes to other adjacent nodes in the network. For this I have written a Node class.

I understand generally how to complete the problem of simulating the network, but my problem is this: if I want a Node to send a message to another Node, how should I name the methods for best readability? I currently have something like this:

```
class Node:
    def send_message( self, othernode, message ):
        othernode.receive_message( self, message )

    def receive_message( self, othernode, message ):
        # do something with the message
```

But something about the term "receive_message" feels wrong. Is there a standard for this situation?

Comment: `put` and `get` are common method names. Do you want the system to work as a drop in replacement for something like `Queue.Queue`? In that case, its methods would be the best.

Comment: I'm fond of "dispatch" and "handle" for message delivery

Comment: 'Send' and 'receive' are fine. 'Dispatch' and 'handle' as mentioned by Benjamin are also good. Either way, consistency throughout your program is best. You might want better names than 'othernode' though. Something like 'destination' and 'origin'.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the ideas. I suppose my main problem is that when I want a send a message _to_ a node, then I would call node.receive_message( message ).